# Allow embed tag in HTMLPurifier?

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I use this configuration:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8');
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Strict');
$config->set('HTML.SafeObject', true);
$config->set('Output.FlashCompat', true);
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'object[width|height|data],param[name|value],embed[src|type|allowscriptaccess|allowfullscreen|width|height|wmode]');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

But all embed tags like this are getting stripped:

```
<embed allowfullscreen="true" height="480" src="apps/viral_player/player-viral.swf?file=../../data/media/video/1.flv" width="720" wmode="transparent"></embed>
```

Is there any way to get HTMLPurifier not strip embed tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try HTML.SafeEmbed?